# What is the difference between next() and next('route') in an expressjs app.VERB call?

Tags: node.js, express

The docs read:

> The app.VERB() methods provide the routing functionality in Express,
>   where VERB is one of the HTTP verbs, such as app.post(). Multiple
>   callbacks may be give, all are treated equally, and behave just like
>   middleware, with the one exception that these callbacks may invoke
>   next('route') to bypass the remaining route callback(s). This
>   mechanism can be used to perform pre-conditions on a route then pass
>   control to subsequent routes when there is no reason to proceed with
>   the route matched.

What do they mean by "bypass the remaining route callbacks?"? I know that `next()` will pass control to the next matching route. But... what function will get control with `next('route')`...?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I hated it when I answer my own question 5 minutes later.
`next('route')` is when using route middleware. So if you have:

```
app.get('/forum/:fid', middleware1, middleware2, function(){
  // ...
})
```

the function middleware1() has a chance to call `next()` to pass control to middleware2, or `next('route')` to pass control to the next matching route altogether.

Comment: The API is weird.  It would make more sense if they used `next()` and `next_route()`, or something like that.  Or even `next_middleware()` and `next_route()`.  Using the same method for both, with one taking a fixed string argument to basically make it do something very different—that's pretty unexpected.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it better for me.  I was thinking you could call something like `next('users/:userId')` or something like that from the way it looked in the docs. From your comment it sounds like you can only pass the constant string `'route'` **always**.

Comment: @iconoclast plus if you call `next(error)`, you will end up in the error catch all if you have defined one... One call to rule them all :-)

Comment: Also, `next` just an identifier name and we can call it anything. so, one function argument should be sufficient with `next('route')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495319/is-it-possible-to-have-conditional-routes-in-expressjs

Answer (score 1):

The given answer explains the main gist of it. Sadly, it is much less intuitive than you might think, with a lot of special cases when it is used in combination with parameters. Just check out some of the test cases in [the app.param test file](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/test/app.param.js). Just to raise two examples:

1. [app .param(name, fn) should defer all the param routes](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/test/app.param.js#L281) implies that if `next("route")` is called from a `param` handler, it would skip all following routes that refer to that `param` handler's own parameter name. In that test case, it skips all routes refering to the `id` parameter.
2. [app .param(name, fn) should call when values differ when using "next"](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/test/app.param.js#L337) suggests that the previous rule has yet another exception: don't skip if the value of the parameter changes between routes.

...and there is more...

I'm sure there is a use-case for this kind of `next('route')` lever, but, I agree with previous comments in that it certainly makes things complicated and non-intuitive.