# Is it possible to have conditional routes in Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

What I want to do

```
if req is from mobile

first check these routes
router.use('/', mobileRoutes);

then ones below
router.use('/', routes);
```

but as far as I understand express goes through all use statements upon every request, it runs them all once and put route handlers into some sort of array. that get hit with requests.

For some urls I want to server different pages but no all (loginPage, registrationPage, etc).

Is it possible to do conditional routing, to prepend more routes in case some condition is met.

What I do have working is this:

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    let md = new MobileDetect(req.headers["user-agent"]);
    if (md.mobile()) {
        req.url = '/mobile'+req.url;
    }
    next();
});

//mobile routes
router.use("/mobile", require("./mobile"));
```

but it completely blocks all routes below.

I want a clean solution, One another option, which is not clean, is to add middleware to individual routes but that muddies code endlessly.

Comment: That looks wrong to me. The purpose of Express and routing is to hit the controller based on some rules. You can decide in controller how you handle it, but you should not modify the routing. Also most of the webpages are redirecting you from something.com to m.something.com when on mobile to achieve some reasonable routing.

Comment: A) I don't want to muddy each controller with isMobile logic separately. 
B) I didn't want `m.domain.com ` because you'd need different routes/controllers when only few pages are different, but couple. also problem with seo?

Comment: Ok, then if you are not doing it for all routes, I suppose "muddying" it in related controllers seems reasonable. The logic about isMobile you can put into middleware in front of all requests and just set something like req.mobile=true, if conditions are met. Then it depends on controller how it handles these

Comment: can't believe it, just found there is a thing called `next('router')` and it worked. https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/3187

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Solution for conditional routing:

**index.js**

```
 .....
//mobile routes
router.use("/", require("./mobile"));

router.get("/", require("./get"));
.....
```

**mobile.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const MobileDetect = require("mobile-detect");

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    let md = new MobileDetect(req.headers["user-agent"]);
    (md.mobile())? next() : next("router")
});


router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send({ query: req.query });
});


module.exports = router;
```