# GET routes nodejs, how it will react if 2 routes are the same?

Tags: node.js, express, get, routes

My team is developing an API nodejs with express and we are wondering if those routes are gonna be in conflict:

- First GET route : /aws/volumes/:id
- Second GET route : /aws/volumes/types

If someone got an information for this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, These routes will conflict. If you provide the routes in the below order, it always hit the first route though you call '/aws/volumes/types'.

- First GET route : /aws/volumes/:id
- Second GET route :    /aws/volumes/types

If you provide the routes as below, then they won't result in conflict.

- First GET route : /aws/volumes/types
- Second GET route : /aws/volumes/:id

Comment: It is clear, thank you. but can I have the link where it said it always hit the first route please ? :)

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.param

Theres a bit of an example here. It depends on how you end the function though, if you end with `next()` it will continue. If you end with `res.end() or res.json()` then it will stop moving to the next route.

Answer (score 1):

They will conflict. For example,

If you define `GET /aws/volumes/:id` first, then all of the below will point to it:

- `GET /aws/volumes/example`
- `GET /aws/volumes/qwerty`
- `GET /aws/volumes/types`

You could alternatively do for the second route to get around the above:

- `GET /aws/volumes?q=types`

Answer (score 0):

The first route matches the request will win! It means that both could match the same request. Thus, you should put the most specific one first, i.e., "/aws/volumes/types". This way, it will run the handler for the "types" route if you request "/aws/volumes/types", otherwise, it will run the handler for the ":id" route.

Also, you can use regular expression if you want to be more precise with what you expect as an ":id". See more here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html in the "route paths" section.

Finally, you can also try `next('route')` instruction in this case. Instead of just calling `next()` which will call the next middleware of the same route, `next('route')` will pass control to the next matching route handler. See the answer here: [What is the difference between next() and next('route') in an expressjs app.VERB call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805371/what-is-the-difference-between-next-and-nextroute-in-an-expressjs-app-verb)